# How can I create data pulses to control a WS2818b LED strip using the MSP430FR4133

Tags: c, microcontroller, msp430, iar

Im trying to write code so that I can control the LED strip. All I want to start with is to learn how to turn the first 1 or 2 LEDs a certain colour. I have no idea how to actually implement this. Particularly unsure about how to output a data pulse from a GPIO pin.

I think i should use PWM to create the data pulse but im struggling to get started. I know that I need to send 24 bits to control the LED strip but not sure how this is possible using a GPIO pin. Any advice on where I can look to get started would be really appreciated. There seems to be lots of resources for this on the Arduino but struggling to find much for the MSP430.

Comment: those leds require careful timing, depends on the peripherals available, so I cant remember if spi can be used vs pwm vs timer.  you are going to need a scope so you can see the signals.   If you dont have the tools/experience, you might want to use some other mcu that already has examples to support these leds.

Comment: I think you want to setup hardware timer with constant speed rather than PWM. Then simply toggle GPIO pin up or down on timer interrupt. Finally stop timer when there has been 24 interrupts.